# Code won't stop file from saving when certain cells have no contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on some code which is supposed to check to make sure that the cells at the bottom of the page in the D column have contents in them before it will let the user save the file, but for some reason it does not do this, and I am allowed to save the file even when those cells are empty, and I am unsure as to why. 
I put this code into the 'ThisWorkbook" object as a BeforeSave action. The primary way this code will be saved is by using a button which I made to automatically save the file to a specific location, but the same thing occurs when I save it manually.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim names As Variant 
Dim name As Variant
names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3") 'set up array of sheet names

For Each name In names 'check to see if cell is filled out or not
    If Worksheets(name).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).value = 0 
        MsgBox "Save cancelled. Sheet " & name & " is missing signature."
    Cancel = True 'stop save from occurring
    End If

Next name

End Sub
```

So essentially, I want it to go through specific sheets called out by name - I've changed the sheet names and the number of sheets for this post but I don't think that should impact how the code works - check them to see if they have contents in the last row of column D (which will be empty unless the user puts information in) and then if any of these cells are empty, to not let the user continue saving the file until the signatures have at least some contents. It does none of this, allows the file to save, and gives me the error message, "Runtime error '9' Subscript out of range." I would appreciate any help with this issue!

Comment: On which line do you have the error?

Comment: you are checking if the value is Zero in the last used row of column 4, where if it is blank it will be ""

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that in the question to begin with. The error occurs on the 6th line, during the "if" statement.

Comment: you need to qualify ALL of your ranges... `Worksheets(name).Cells(Worksheets(name).Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp),4).value = ""`  Notice that I put a column reference in the Cells() reference (you forgot the column 4 outside of the last row check)

Comment: @Cyril yeah, I thought that was what I should do so that if it checks  to see if it is blank and it is blank, then it cancels the save and tells the user which sheets are blank. Did I completely structure my code incorrectly?

Comment: @Andrew Your "last row" will have content unless there is no content in the column.  the position of the last row may be more important, since `If Worksheets(name).Cells(lr, 4).value = "" Then ` can only be blank if `lr = 1` and there is no content

Comment: @Cyril I made those changes, but now it doesn't even compile, getting stuck on the same line. Here is what I have now:

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim names As Variant
Dim name As Variant
names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

For Each name In names
    If Worksheets(name).Cells(Worksheets(name).Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp),4).value = "" Then
    
    MsgBox "Save cancelled. Sheet " & name & " is missing signature."
    Cancel = True
    End If
    
Next name

End Sub

Comment: @Andrew if you are posting code, please edit your post as it's nearly impossible to read more than a line or two in comments.  See my answer for a possible rectification for the structuring, which doesn't sound too far off considering you know your data better than we do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POsting comment as answer:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim names As Variant 
Dim name As Variant
Dim lr as Long 'ADDED
names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3") 'set up array of sheet names

For Each name In names 'check to see if cell is filled out or not
    With Sheets(name)
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'ADDED
        If .Cells(lr, 4).value = "" Then 'CHANGED, but does not make sense as written unless NOTHING exists in column D (4)
            MsgBox "Save cancelled. Sheet " & name & " is missing signature."
            Cancel = True 'stop save from occurring
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next name

End Sub
```

---

**Edit1:**

In regard to your comment about the structure being incorrect, you will most likely want to check the last row based on ANOTHER column.

As we cannot see your sheet, I will assume that there is a Header for signature in the adjacent cell, which might work to your advantage.  Might look like:

```
Cells(lr,3)    |    Cells(lr,4)
Signature:     |    ""
```

If the above is a true scenario, you can modify the above code to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim names As Variant 
Dim name As Variant
Dim lr as Long 'ADDED
names = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3") 'set up array of sheet names

For Each name In names 'check to see if cell is filled out or not
    With Sheets(name)
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'ADDED
        If .Cells(lr, 4).value = "" Then 'CHANGED, but does not make sense as written unless NOTHING exists in column D (4)
            MsgBox "Save cancelled. Sheet " & name & " is missing signature."
            Cancel = True 'stop save from occurring
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next name

End Sub
```

The only change is in the line defining `lr` where I swapped the column from 4 to 3.

Comment: You can add `Exit For` after the `Cancel = True`

Comment: @AAA just added that; nice catch... made a couple other tweaks (with statement and more comments to explain)

Comment: That is PERFECT. Thanks so much. I really appreciate it!